# vectorization of two for loop (matrix creation and thresholding)

Tags: matlab, vectorization

How to vectorize this MATLAB function:

```
function [win,vec] = createwin(data,shift,regions,threshold)
% 
% data      ... 1D data array
% shift     ... positive integer scalar
% regions   ... integer index vector 
% threshold ... integer scalar
%
win = zeros(length(data),2*shift+1);
for i = 1+shift:length(data)-shift
   win(i,:) = data(i-shift:i+shift);
end

vec = false(size(data));
for i = 1:length(regions)
    ii = max(1+shift, regions(i)-shift):min(length(data)-shift, regions(i)+shift);
    vec(ii) = data(ii) >= threshold & data(ii) >= win(ii);
end
```

I am just adding second for-loop, which is now bottleneck in this code.
So, any idea how to vectorize the second loop?

and some test case:

```
[win,vec]=createwin(1:20,3,[2:18],10)
```

expected result is:

win =

```
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7
 2     3     4     5     6     7     8
 3     4     5     6     7     8     9
 4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 5     6     7     8     9    10    11
 6     7     8     9    10    11    12
 7     8     9    10    11    12    13
 8     9    10    11    12    13    14
 9    10    11    12    13    14    15
10    11    12    13    14    15    16
11    12    13    14    15    16    17
12    13    14    15    16    17    18
13    14    15    16    17    18    19
14    15    16    17    18    19    20
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

vec =

```
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: Is `data` a matrix or a vector? To clarify, post a small example with input (`data`, `shift`) and output (`win`)

Comment: It would be good if you posted sample input and output. It's easier to verify a solution then.

Comment: Also some sample values for  data and shift and then show the output, win?

Comment: That's not the `win` I get when I run your code. How can your `win` have 10 rows when `length(data) = 8`?

Comment: Ah, I see. Typing error probably. Should be `win = createwin(1:10,2)` rather than `createwin(1:8,2)`.

Comment: @kkuilla Yup! That's what it looks like!

Comment: This question is much more complete now compared to the first version. It deserves an upvote now...

Comment: Regarding the edited codes where you have posted query on vectorizing another loop and even though its borrowing input `win` from the first loop, but functionally it would be a lot different. So, I would suggest posting a new question on that. Thanks!

Comment: OK ... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865326/vectorization-of-for-loop-thresholding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach with [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
win = zeros(size(data,1),2*shift+1)
row_id = 1+shift:size(data,1)-shift
win(row_id,:) = data(bsxfun(@plus,row_id(:),[-shift:shift]))
```

Please note that for pre-allocation, you can also use this [`faster scheme`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance) -

```
win(size(data,1),2*shift+1) = 0;
```

Comment: OK ... nice solution with ~ 20x speed up :)

Comment: Thanks for Yair's article about pre-allocation @Divakar that's very useful!